# Is this the correct way to use the lambda and map function to execute this piece of code

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda

I am having this confusion or gap in my understanding while executing this piece of code. I tried couple of ways to resolve the issue but I am unable to do so. What would be the correct way to resolve this.

```
find_max = map(lambda a, b, c: a if a > b and a > c
                   else (b if b > a and b > c else c), (2, 3, 4))
print(list(find_max))
```

I got the bellow error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'b' and 'c'
```

I tweaked the above code

```
find_max=map(lambda a:a[0] if a[0]>a[1] and a[0]>a[2] 
    else (a[1] if a[1]>a[0] and a[1]>a[2] else a[2]),(2,3,4))
print(list(find_max))
```

I got the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 1, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Then I tweaked further

```
find_max=map(lambda *a:a[0] if a[0]>a[1] and a[0]>a[2] 
    else (a[1] if a[1]>a[0] and a[1]>a[2] else a[2]),(2,3,4))
print(list(find_max))
``

I got the below error

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<input>", line 1, in <lambda>
    IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output, your tuple/dictionary/list

Comment: `map` takes a callable, and that callable will be provided a *single argument*.

Comment: `find_max` seems to want to *find the maximum value in an iterable*. This is **not a use-case for `map` at all**. Map takes an iterable and apply a function to each of those elements, i.e. it *maps the function onto the elements of the itereble*. The iterator itself will always have as many elements as the original iterable.  You don't want to use `map` here at all.

Comment: Note, you actually haven't explained at all what you are trying to accomplish, leaving us to guess, which is really shouldn't be the case, you should always provide a full problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `map` here, you just want to *call* the function:

```
(lambda a, b, c: a if a > b and a > c else (b if b > a and b > c else c)) (2, 3, 4)
```

Your 2nd tweak can work if you `map` to e.g. a list containing a single triplet:

```
list(map(lambda a:a[0] if a[0]>a[1] and a[0]>a[2] else (a[1] if a[1]>a[0] and a[1]>a[2] else a[2]),[(2,3,4)]))
# returns [4]
```

Comment: but *this is absurd*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 'absurd' as 'why not just use `max`? I assume this is just an exercise...

Comment: As in creating an anonymous function simply to invoke it immediately. Also an absurd use of `map`, it's *not a correct use of `map`*. When people ask a question, "how do I shoot myself in the foot", you should answer, "don't shoot yourself in the foot".

Answer (score 1):

When you call `map(fn, iterable)`, it invokes the given `fn` on each *individual element* of `iterable`.  That means that your `lambda` is being invoked on `2`, `3`, and `4` in turn; it's never getting all three of them as parameters at the same time.

It is not really possible to implement a "find maximum" operation as a call to `map`, since you ultimately want to get a single result, and `map` will give you one result for each element of the input iterable.

The simple solution, of course, is to just use the built-in `max()` function:

```
>>> max((2, 3, 4))
4
```

If you want to implement your own version of `max`, you probably don't want to use `map` and `lambda`, since finding a maximum value requires you to iterate over all the elements while tracking the largest one (meaning it needs a local variable and a loop, both of which are awkward to accomplish in a lambda):

```
>>> def find_max(iterable):
...     m = None
...     for i in iterable:
...         if m is None or m < i:
...             m = i
...     return m
...
>>> find_max((2, 3, 4))
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that, `map` would operate each element.
In the first example, you made two mistakes.

`map(lambda ...., (2, 3, 4))`, In this example, python try to do your lambda function for each element, like `lambda 2, ?, ?: xx`, `lambda 3, ?, ?: xx`, `lambda 4, ?, ?: xx`.(That's why it gave you:`<lambda>() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'b' and 'c'`)

Then firstly, you may need to pass a list of tuple to `map`

And also note that, python has removed [`Tuple Parameter Unpacking`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

So the way(wouldn't raise exception, but is strange):

```
find_max=map(lambda a:a[0] if a[0]>a[1] and a[0]>a[2] 
    else (a[1] if a[1]>a[0] and a[1]>a[2] else a[2]),[(2,3,4)])
print(list(find_max))
```

---

there is no need to use `map`, though.

Answer (score 1):

You **don't want to use `map` at all here**. You are trying to find the maximum value in an iterable, that isn't a mapping operation, that is a reduction. If you want to use functional programming primitives, you are looking for reduce:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda acc, x: x if x > acc else acc, (2, 3, 4))
4
```

Of course, you can just use the built-in `max`, which is what you *should use*. And even if you were going to implement something like this, a naive, looping implementation is more idiomatic (of course, that is a matter of style).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find_max = map(lambda a:a[0] if (a[0]>a[1] and a[0]>a[2]) 
               else (a[1] if a[1]>a[0] and a[1]>a[2] 
               else a[2]), [[2,3,4]])
```

The argument must be a list in a list.

Comment: **but this is absurd**

Comment: It surely is, but I'm not here to judge. Just want to help.

Comment: It isn't helpful to show people how to do things the wrong way